# Get the response of one controller in another controller in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am facing an issue to get the response from one controller inside another controller.

How do I get the response from getUserAppointmentDetails.js to respondAppointment.js file

```
   getUserAppointmentDetails.js

   const con = require('./../database_connection');

   exports.getUserAppointmentDetails = function (req, res, next) {
       // const details = req.body;
       con.query('SELECT * from user_appointment_details WHERE id = 1', (err,
   respond) => {
           if (err) throw err;

           res.send({result: respond});
    });
   }


   Another file
   respondAppointment.js

   const con = require('./../database_connection');
   const userDetails = require('./getUserAppointmentDetails');

   exports.respondAppointment = function (req, res, next) {
       const details = req.body;
       con.query('update user_appointment_details SET status = "' + details.status
           + '" WHERE id = ' + details.id,
           (err, respond) => {
           if (err) throw err;

           res.send({result: respond});
    });

    var userData = userDetails.getUserAppointmentDetails(req, res, next);
    }
```

Please respond if anyone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are sending the response in both and not actually returning the result in callback from another function.

Assuming that you want the result of `getUserAppointmentDetails.js` in `respondAppointment.js`. Make the change in `getUserAppointmentDetails.js` and `getUserAppointmentDetails.js` to return the value to the calling function.

**getUserAppointmentDetails.js**

```
 const con = require('./../database_connection');

   exports.getUserAppointmentDetails = function (idToGet) {
       // const details = req.body;
       con.query('SELECT * from user_appointment_details WHERE id = '+idToGet, (err,
   respond) => {
           if (err) throw err;

           return respond;
    });
   }
```

**Another file:
   respondAppointment.js**

```
const con = require('./../database_connection');
   const userDetails = require('./getUserAppointmentDetails');

   exports.respondAppointment = function (req, res, next) {

   const details = req.body;

   var userData = userDetails.getUserAppointmentDetails(details.id);
    console.log(userData);

       con.query('update user_appointment_details SET status = "' + details.status
           + '" WHERE id = ' + details.id,
           (err, respond) => {
           if (err) throw err;

           res.send({result: respond});
    });


    }
```

Comment: It did not work for me. I am getting the data from db inside getUserAppointmentDetails.js file but not able to retrieve that in respondAppointment.js file

Comment: @DKB can you try to call the function before you send out the response like i have done in the example above

Comment: I have found that the the data from mysql is getting delay of some fraction second and it does not wait for mysql response to return. If you have any idea then please let me know.